# Backbone routing and #

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, url-routing

I have some problem with backbone and the routing.

Here's the code:

```
    //routing
    var AppRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({
        routes: {
            "":"home",
            "example": "example",
            "example/:data": "example_data"
        },
        home: function(){
            alert('home');
        },
        example: function(){
            alert('example');
        },
        example_data: function(data){
            alert('example '+data);
        }
    });

    var app_router = new AppRouter();
    //Backbone.history.start({pushState: true});
    Backbone.history.start();
```

Now if i go the root url:

```
file:///Users/my_user/workspace/project/index.html
```

I can see the alert 'home'.
If i change the url to

```
file:///Users/my_user/workspace/project/index.html#example
```

I can see the alert 'example', and if i change the url to:

```
file:///Users/my_user/workspace/project/index.html#example/something
```

i can see the alert 'example something'.

Right now i have two problems: the first is that i would really appreciate to delete the '#' symbol and using a '/' instead. The second problem is that if i decomment this line of code:

```
    //Backbone.history.start({pushState: true});
```

Alert do not work anymore. How can I solve this?

Here's the full code of the project:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>App</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id='test-routing'><a href='#example'>example</a></div>
        <div id='test-view'></div>

        <script src="lib/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
        <script src="lib/underscore-min.js"></script>
        <script src="lib/backbone-min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://sdk.amazonaws.com/js/aws-sdk-2.1.26.min.js"></script>

        <script>

        //routing
        var AppRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({
            routes: {
                "":"home",
                "example": "example",
                "example/:data": "example_data"
            },
            home: function(){
                alert('home');
            },
            example: function(){
                alert('example');
            },
            example_data: function(data){
                alert('example '+data);
            }
        });

        var app_router = new AppRouter();
        Backbone.history.start({pushState: true});
        //Backbone.history.start();

        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

to your first question, I believe you were on the right path of ridding your URLs from hashtags, you can use HTML5 pushState for this.

Some help with that:

http://artsy.github.io/blog/2012/06/25/replacing-hashbang-routes-with-pushstate/

<strike>As for your second question, the reason your application doens't start if you remove</strike>

```
    //Backbone.history.start({pushState: true});
```

is because the backbone router doesn't get started, so it's not listening for hashchange (or pushstate) events, so it won't call your router function which will then (probably) render a view.

You NEED to run Backbone.history.start in order for your router to do anything.

Did you comment out the other Backbone.history.start call? Do you get any errors logged?

I hope this helps

EDIT:

I think this fiddle should help you out:
http://jsfiddle.net/sn21jg3x/

Good luck, tell me if this works.

Comment: Yes, i commented the other line of code! I can't do a jsfiddle but I have updated the first answer with  the code of the project!

Comment: I think I found the solution to your problem, I'll update my answer now.

Comment: Thank you, i added the code you gave me and the problem of the '#' is solved, on the other hand, if I navigate with the link/button on my project i can see the link changeing with '/' (www.project.com -> www.project.com/resource) but if i directly paste something like www.project.com/resource nothing is found.